# How to encrypt a file using EncFS and C++?

Tags: c++, encryption, filesystems

EncFS is an open source encrypted file system.

It is really easy to use a compiled encfs executable for Windows and nix systems to encrypt whole directories and mount them.

I just want to encrypt one file programmatically with C++. I couldn't find any libraries on the official website http://www.arg0.net/encfs

How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you call `encfs` from C++ to create a container, put the file there and unmount the container, when you finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you cannot create a single encrypted file with an encrypted file system, unless you create a filesystem with just one file as math suggested (in a comment).

Alternatives are using the CMS or PGP to create a single encrypted file. Both are container formats that can be used for different forms of encryption. There are other container formats but many are proprietary, CMS and PGP are open and standardized.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One more question then. Is there a way to decrypt just the file names? I store the encrypted files on the server  and don't to download them just to display the file names.